# Loops on dataframes & replace

Tags: python, dataframe

I need to add a new column to my dataframe (Titanic dataset) call Range, with the range of every passenger on the Titanic, following this table:

```
Kids  11 years
Young 18 years
Adult  50 years
Old 50 years
```

I created a new column and full it with NaN. Then, I have tried a loop to itinerate the age and replace the value of the column, but the column fills all the rows with 'Adult'. Why can this be happening?

```
for i in df["Age"]:
    if (i < 11.0):
        df["Range"] = df['Range'].replace(['NaN'],'Kid')
    elif (i < 18.0):
        df["Range"] = df['Range'].replace(['NaN'],'Young')
    elif (i < 50.0):
        df["Range"] = df['Range'].replace(['NaN'],'Adult')
    elif (i >= 50.0):
        df["Range"] = df['Range'].replace(['NaN'],'Old')
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Looping over dataframe values is highly inefficient, there are specific methods designed to accomplish these mapping tasks, e.g. you can apply custom functions to dataframes using `apply()`. Could you include a sample of your dataframe, as well as your desired output?

Comment: Please include a sample of this dataset in your original question, do not include it as a link.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, its a better way:

```
def label_range(row):
    if row["Age"] < 11:
       return "Kid"
    if row["Age"] < 18:
       return "Young"
    .
    .
    #Other conditions
    .
    return "Other"

 df['Range'] = df.apply (lambda row: label_range(row), axis=1)
```